# How, on ubuntu, to run as a service / run under supervision

Tags: ubuntu, services, amazon-ec2

I have been given 3 clusters.  One is of Kafka, one is of storm and one is of ZooKeeper.  I need to make it so that the services start and when stopped, start up again as described in the [Zookeeper admin guide](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_supervision).

```
OS for every machine => Ubuntu-trusty 14.04
Platform => Running in Amazon EC2
```

So, to recap, I need to be able to start the respective service at startup.  If the service starts, I need it to get restarted.  I need to do this for Storm, Kafka, and Zookeeper.  And I need the answer to be simple and direct. Another way to ask this question:  What is the easiest way to accomplish my goals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service management mechanism for Ubuntu is Upstart.
The Upstart guide is here:
http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/

It's not so hard to get going. There are lots of examples you can crib.

It turns out (from our chat linked in the comments) that @MassSql has services that background (and presumably monitor/restart themselves if they die). Given that's the case, he can use the simpler/legacy RC script mechanism (which is implemented by Upstart, but a much simpler interface for simpler tasks of just starting things at boot and stopping them at shutdown). So here's that approach:

1. Go to /etc/init.d, and make a copy of dns-clean (rename it as you
   like).
2. Edit the file. Change the `INIT INFO` section by altering the descriptions and clearing out the `Required-Start` and `Required-Stop` fields. Make a new name for `Provides`.
   (basically change everything but `Default-Start`)
3. Delete these lines:

> test -f /usr/sbin/pppconfig || exit 0
>
> mkdir /var/run/pppconfig >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
>
> test -f /etc/ppp/ip-down.d/0dns-down || exit 0

4. Change the lines in the `start)` block to run your scripts. Leave the `;;` at the end.
5. Run `update-rc.d foobar enable` where `foobar` is the name of your service (should be the name of the file as well as the `Provides`, at least by convention).

Reboot your system and test.

Comment: Is upstart already installed?

Comment: Yes Upstart should be installed on any base Ubuntu distro. You can verify by doing: "dpkg-query -l upstart"

Comment: Perhaps what I really need is an example upstart guide to follow?  Step 1, create job, Step 2 create event.

Comment: Do you really need events? Or do you just want to run a job that gets started at boot and restarted when it dies? Maybe you can be more specific about what kind of events you want to handle, and the relationship/dependencies of your job to other jobs on the system (if any).

Comment: I want the service to start when the OS starts.  I want the service to start if it has been stopped.

Comment: Well, at a guess I'd say you don't want it to start if you stop it manually :-). This is the sort of thing Upstart does very easily. I'll update my answer with an example. You do need to know something about how the service starts: i.e. does it just run in the foreground? Or does it fork itself into the background? Does it fork twice (this is common for some services)?

Comment: The scripts seem to have -service flags.  That is all I know.

Comment: You'll have to do your own footwork. I won't research it for you. Try running it by hand. Do you get a shell prompt, while it runs in background, or does it keep running in the foreground?

Comment: The process begins running in the background.  A command prompt is returned.  How do I tell how many times it forks?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not so easy. You'd need to use strace. Is there a man page? Is there an option to run it in foreground? I'm going to try moving this discussion to chat, as StackExchange keeps nudging us to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20045/discussion-between-bobdoolittle-and-maassql).